# Is there a way to query a main-thread realm instance without blocking the main thread?

Tags: c#, realm

**realm-dotnet**

I'd like to pass some main-thread realm objects to some view-models, but don't want to block the UI while I retrieve them.

I need realm objects from a main-thread realm instance so that myRealmObject.PropertyChanged is called on the main thread.  If no background query, is there a way to make a background-thread realm object's PropertyChanged be called on the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query on a background thread and create a `ThreadSafeReference` that you can pass to your VMs. For example:

```
var reference = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (var realm = Realm.GetInstance())
    {
        var modelToPass = realm.All<MyModel>().Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
        return ThreadSafeReference.Create(modelToPass);
    }
});
// Pass reference to your ViewModel
```

Then in your ViewModel you can have

```
public void Initialize(ThreadSafeReference.Object<MyModel> reference)
{
    var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    var myModel = realm.ResolveReference(reference);
    // Do stuff with myModel - it's a main thread reference to
    // the model you resolved on the background thread
}
```

Check out [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!  Performance wise, is calling ResolveReference on a large number of references (measurably) faster than just querying a main-thread-realm for them once?

Comment: Depends on your query type - if you're just looking up object by PK, then no. If you're doing complex lookup, that may involve a table scan (e.g. search by string contains or something similar), then yes. Roughly speaking, `ResolveReference` has similar performance to a PK lookup, but has the benefit of being available even for objects that don't have a primary key.